# iPhone X Keyboard Input Accessory View freeze bug

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, iphone-x, inputaccessoryview

I have set the input accessory view to be a container view containing a UITextField. With all the iPhoneXs, as I slowly drag the keyboard down to the bottom, the screen freezes. I haven't been coding for long and I have no idea where to even begin to fix the issue as nothing shows up in the debug view and it's only an issue with the iPhone Xs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The bottom is the code in the view controller relating to the input accessory view:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return containerView
    }
}


lazy var containerView: ChatInputAccessoryView = {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
    let chatInputAccessoryView = ChatInputAccessoryView(frame: frame)
    chatInputAccessoryView.delegate = self
    return chatInputAccessoryView
}()
```

Comment: What happened with CPU and memory when iPhone freezes? Do you see 100% of CPU usage?

Comment: Yea CPU went up to around 90% when it was previously down at 10, and memory began growing at 5mb each second. It also looks like the KeyboardWillShow notification is continuously called since the debug view kept printing the print statement I placed inside the function.